# Jmeter does not show through a remote desktop (xrdp)

Tags: user-interface, jmeter, xrdp

I now the best practices with Jmeter, but I need to run it in GUI mode.

I have installed jmeter v5.2 on a CentOS virtual machine and I get connected through remote desktop from a windows machine. Jmeter runs normally when I execute from the virtual machine. 
[Jmeter direct from virtual machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8v632.png)

The problem is when I connect through a remote desktop, then I start Jmeter and I get this:
[Jmeter from remote desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kvHV.png)

I review the logs from xrdp and there is nothing wrong, can u help me please, some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to update your Java to latest version, it might be the case you're suffering from a bug.

If this doesn't help - try setting adding the following lines to *system.properties*

```
sun.java2d.opengl=true
sun.java2d.xrender=false
```

you might also want to not to use this dark theme, try setting different look and feel, i.e. System, in *user.properties*

```
jmeter.laf=System
```

More information:

- [How to Set the Look and Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)
- [System Properties for Java 2D Technology](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html)